# How to activate duplicate feature on my new activity in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I created a new activity on Moodle but I found that duplicate feature isn't working .
is there any way to solve these problem .
after searching i found that i have to add backup folder in the folder of my activity
but i don't know if that true or not

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using Moodle, it should be directed instead at the Moodle developers, or the admin of the service which is hosting the asker's Moodle site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to populate the backup files for your plugin - see details at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Backup_API

Your PLUGINNAME_supports() function in lib.php will also need to return true for FEATURE_BACKUP_MOODLE2

I usually start with something like mod_forum in the core code and use that as the basis for my activity plugin backup & restore code.